# Need Assistance with Confusing MySQL Query Issue

Tags: mysql

Ok, Having a hard time figuring out how to do this query.

I have a billing log table that contains the following fields:

```
+----+---------+--------+--------------+
| ID | OrderID | FileID | CollectionID |
+----+---------+--------+--------------+
|  1 |     113 |   3666 |          345 |
|  2 |     113 |  35354 |          345 |
|  3 |     113 |   3456 |          345 |
|  4 |     113 |   7734 |          345 |
|  5 |     114 |     23 |              |
|  6 |     115 |    442 |              |
|  7 |     116 |    115 |              |
|  8 |     117 |   5141 |          987 |
|  9 |     117 |   1423 |          987 |
| 10 |     118 |    213 |              |
| 11 |     119 |   3666 |          345 |
| 12 |     119 |  35354 |          345 |
| 13 |     119 |   3456 |          345 |
| 14 |     119 |  44142 |          345 |
| 15 |     120 |  12321 |              |
| 16 |     121 |    789 |         1113 |
| 17 |     122 |  78000 |              |
| 18 |     123 |   9987 |              |
| 19 |     124 |   7899 |          345 |
| 20 |     124 |     87 |          345 |
| 21 |     124 |     78 |          345 |
+----+---------+--------+--------------+
```

I am trying to get the number of times a collection was purchased.   In the above example, Collection number 345 was purchased 3 times, collection 987 was purchased once and  collection 1113 was purchased once.

To clarify that point if you look at IDs 1-4 you can see that someone purchased Collection number 345 which includes the following files (3666, 35354, 3456 and 7734) and their order number for that purchase was 113.

So we have a table full of these and I just need to know how many times each collection was purchased.

Any idears?

Thanks for your help!

Craig

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Look up `GROUP BY` and `COUNT (DISTINCT ...)`.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Off topic comment: I've found this resource great for formatting tables http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: @Marcus I was wondering how you have pretty formatted that table so quickly ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks very much for popping in and formatting the table.  It was in need of some love.  Very nice.  I tried all sorts of combinations and groups to no avail.  Andreas' answer below worked great.  Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it. The key is [`distinct OrderID`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

```
select CollectionID, count(distinct OrderID)
  from myTable
 group by CollectionID
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0ae4/1) that shows the result

Comment: That seems to work swimmingly.  Thanks very much for your help Andreas!!

Comment: select MediaBoxID, count(distinct OrderID) from ptpl_billing_log group by MediaBoxID

Answer (score 0):

yeah.. you can use the following query : SELECT *column_name* COUNT(*) FROM *table_name* WHERE CollectionID = '345';

Hope this helps.. Also, a good resource for any Mysql queries is "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/#manual"